# Paste PDF files as email attachments into Outlook for Mac (Office 365)

Tags: ms-office, macos

When I copy a PDF file in Finder and try to paste the file into Outlook 365 for Mac, a picture of the file is pasted into the email message instead of adding the file as an attachment.

Is there any way to change this to paste the file as an attachment instead?

I know that I can drag files from Finder onto the message, but that's annoying because I need to have both windows on the screen at once and I normally do everything full-screen. I know I can hold the dragged file over the dock icon, but that's also hard when there are
many Outlook windows open. Instead, I want to just use the keyboard: Cmd+C to copy the file, Cmd+Tab to go back to my Outlook message, and Cmd+V to paste the file as an attachment.

I'm running the latest version 16.72.2 of Outlook for Mac, if it matters.

Comment: Adding additional information... it depends on what you are trying to paste into the Compose window.  If you Cmd-C an image file, then Cmd-V that, what you get is an inline image (the image contents, not a pic of the file).  So what sort of file are you trying to paste?

Comment: As noted above, it's a PDF file. Thanks!